# Get image from other ASP.Net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

This is my first project:

[image]

This is where I have to access the images stored in other project (shown below):

[image]

Both projects are stored in the same drive.

[image]

Now, how can I display the images in CEEXAM Project when the images are stored in Admin Pages project?

**P.S.: Projects are both running in IIS.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally figured it out. It works well now. I did not copy-paste the image folder from one project to other because it's obviously not a good idea. What I did was in the IIS, I created a `Virtual Directory` for the CEEXAM Project that points to the image folder located in Admin Pages Project. (since both projects are deployed in IIS and running in one production server)

Comment: As the image folders where for sites running under IIS you could also have referenced the images from the other site by their URL